# HTTP Request from a PC to load the contents of a wap site

Tags: get, httprequest, wap

When I try to load a wap site with PHP HTTP request from my PC, host of the web site recognizes that I'm sending the request from a PC and redirects me to their actual web site and I can't load the wap site. Is there a way to behave like a mobile browser and prevent this redirection? Although an answer regarding any programming language is ok, a php specific answer will be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is normally dictated by the User-Agent string on the HTTP request.  You can usually spoof the User-Agent string, and replace it with the user-agent of a mobile device, or if you're using Firefox, you can download a User-Agent Switcher plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Change your [user agent.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)

[This site](http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/) is helpful too as many sites use this code or similar to identify mobile devices.